# Confusion Matrix probability and efficiency

Tags: regression, logistic

some of you have kindly tried to steer me on this question before and it's beginning to sink in, probably. I get that in the matrix below I have set the probability to 0.1 which is giving me an efficiency of 0.59 or 59%.  How do I articulate this?  My model is 59% accurate for a probability of 0.1. I'm not sure what to say. Or am I saying that for a probability of 0.1 the model has an efficiency of 59%.  if I up he p=0.5 I get the error below but around 90% accuracy.  I have an AUC of .61 which seems to mary with the 0.59 at P=0.1.  A line on how to bring all these values together would help me understand tremendously. help gratefully received

I have created the following confusion

working$Predict <- ifelse(modelfit$fitted.values >0.1,"1","0")

mytable <- table(working$Train,working$Predict)

rownames(mytable) <- c("not Trained","Trained")

colnames(mytable) <- c("0","1")

mytable

```
             0    1
```

Not Trained 2668 1854

Trained      176  260

> efficiency <- sum(diag(mytable))/sum(mytable)

> efficiency

[1] 0.5905607

when is set to 0.5 I get the following with an error.  I know have non greater than 0.2.

working$Predict <- ifelse(modelfit$fitted.values >0.5,"1","0")

> mytable <- table(working$Train,working$Predict)

> rownames(mytable) <- c("Not Trained","Trained")

> colnames(mytable) <- c("0","1")

Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :

length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

> mytable

```
             0
```

Not trained 4522

Trained     436

> efficiency <- sum(diag(mytable))/sum(mytable)

> efficiency

[1] 0.9120613

Answer (score 1):

Without reference to the former questions, I'm not sure how groups were formed or your main objective.

Maybe you want a chi-squared test of the null hypothesis
that there is no significant difference between proportions of $0$'s and $1$s for trained and
not trained groups: P-value near $0$ indicates strong significance.

```
MAT = rbind(c(175,260), c(2668, 1854))
MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  175  260
[2,] 2668 1854

chisq.test(MAT, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 57.163, df = 1, p-value = 4.012e-14
```

Comment: I have a binary output trained and not trained with a number of independent variables. I am trying to test my model.  Above is the outputs I get depending on what value I set p to. II am keen for an interpretation of the output to help me understand.  i.e  P=0.1 =59% and an auc of 0.61

Answer (score 1):

AUC is merely a plot of FPR vs. FNR or sens. vs. 1-spec. as a function of your probability threshold.  Accuracy has nothing to do with AUC, since AUC is hinged to sens and spec.  To prove this point, consider a classifier that is a shoe box, which does nothing.  If you present 100 objects to the shoe box and 95 are truly normal and 5 are truly diseased, and the shoe box does nothing, it will be 95% accurate at class prediction, since it assigned normal to all 100 objects, and only misclassified 5 objects -- so it was 95% accurate.  (some classifiers don't respond to certain objects, and therefore are called "weak classifiers," for which boosting can be applied).  The same relationship does not hold for sens and spec, or AUC, which will catch how poorly the shoe box is at classifying.

Comment: Thanks.  so what you are saying is the model does not really identify anything at 0.5 as there are no probabilities above 0.5 %.  The 91% I get are just the figures as in you analogy presented to the shoebox.  However,  could you provide a simple analogy for the  0.61 AUC value and how it associates with 91%?

Comment: AUC is the probability that when presenting a diseased subject (failure) to a classifier, it classifies it as diseased.  An AUC of 0.61 is quite realistic in the "real-world" when practice and training datasets aren't used.